# Firebase filtering and add to list the results

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i just want to filter the queries when conditions true query " norequest >= 5 " it should get the those query or doc's " coordinates " and add the results to a list. How can i do that? [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on [queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries) already? That should allow you to answer at least the first half of the use-case. If you then also look at the documentation on [listening for updates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) you can see how to use a `StreamBuilder` to show those documents in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to declare `norequest` field to Integer.
2. Then you got a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` where you can set many filter

Code example:

```
QuerySnapshot query = await firestore
    .collection('stations')
    .where('norequest', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 5)
    .get();
```

Comment: When i try to list  it says  A value of type 'List<Object?>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Comment: Really sorry... a little bit confused today, fix on the code...

Comment: Ok i fixed by add As List<Map<String, dynamic>>